# How do I navigate to the next squiggly in the current file or project?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Often when I make bigger refactorings in my TypeScript codebase, I'd like to be able to navigate to the next underlined TS compiler error to fix it, then move on further etc. If I use "go to next problem" that always triggers a relatively big red popup message around that line. I would prefer for the cursor to simply jump to that position, I don't require any extra navigation etc. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get a simpler answer I think you may need a macro to do this so two commands are triggered.  Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this in your settings:

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.nextError",
  "sequence": [

    "editor.action.marker.nextInFiles",
    "closeMarkersNavigation",
  ]
},
```

and then in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "F8",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.nextError" },
  "when": "editorFocus && !editorReadonly"
},

{
  "key": "f8",
  "command": "-editor.action.marker.nextInFiles",
  "when": "editorFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

I get a quick flash when the next `marker` closes so this is not optimal but may be the best you can do.

Comment: Ok, that's a pretty good start, thank you! What does that leading `-` in the second command indicate? Reverse order of command sequence execution?

Comment: The `-` deletes that keybinding.

Comment: I wish "Go to Next Problem" would work at all for me; never does anything.